# Buttons not appearing properly using bootstrap in mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap buttons. This is my code:

```
<div class="form-group padding-left-off padding-right-0 col-xs-12 margin-t-20">
    <a role="button" class="margin-t-0 btn btn-danger btn-block js-continue-btn  xs-width-45p  pull-left" data-attr="js-tab2" href="#">Btn1</a>
    <a role="button" class="margin-t-0 btn btn-danger btn-block js-continue-btn pull-right xs-width-50p " data-attr="js-tab2" href="#">Btn2 </a>
</div>
```

In desktop they are appearing vertically aligned with no space between them like this picture. This is how I want them to appear :

[image: Desktop Btns]

In Mobile they are supposed to appear horizontally aligned with space between them like in this picture:
[image: Mobile Btns]

But the alignment in mobile looks the same as the desktop. What change can I make here to make it work in mobile ?

Comment: I have a question...you say in the desktop they are vertically aligned with no space, as in the image. Is that something you are wanting to happen or do you also want the desktop buttons to look like the bottom image?

Comment: No, the desk top image is fine, but it's the mobile image , that i need to be aligned horizontally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on when you want the Media Query break to be you can add the following CSS to do what you want, I just added it to 767px or smaller

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.btn-block {
    width: auto;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    float: left !important;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0 !important;
 }
}
```

Here is a [**JSFIDDLE BEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vZm5c/)

Hope that helps.